# Error occurred when verifying Text

Tags: selenium-ide, verify

I started using Selenium IDE yesterday. Everything worked well when I executed test cases on some random web sites, but as soon as I start executing test cases on the business software (of the company that I work in), it fails during the process. Test passes until it comes to the point were I want to verify the Text on the web page (I select any text on the page, click the right mouse button and choose option "**verifyText css=h3  selectedtext**"). It reports the following error in the Log:

> [error] Window does not exist. If this looks like a Selenium bug, make
>   sure to read
>   http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows
>   for potential workarounds.

If anyone is willing to help me understand this, please have in mind that I am not a developer.

Comment: Can you paste the code for the page? specifically the part around what you're trying to verify

Comment: Yeah, sure: <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>css=#clUnTree_text39 &gt; a.nav-item</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>selectWindow</td>
 <td>name=main</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>verifyText</td>
 <td>css=h3</td>
 <td>Create New Batch Definition ( Enrichment)</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
The last part reports error (selectWindow and verifyText). I was thinking...could it be because the software was built 15 years ago (not the newest technology), so Selenium can't recognize the structure of the web page or something like that?         Thanks for replying! :) @Sidsec9

Comment: Does your test deal with multiple windows? You may need to investigate the selectWindow command.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it looks like you have a click function, immediately followed by the select window one. Try putting a pause of a few seconds in between these 2. From the error you're getting it may be that your script is trying to select the window before it's loaded the window title. You might also want to change your verify text to a wait for text, again just to avoid the script erroring if the page content hasn't loaded when it tries that check

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check that out and follow your suggestion as soon as I come back from the vacation.